# How do I define the PROVIDER NAME in Configurations on IIS server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, iis, configuration

I uploaded a project in Visual Studio and the database SQL SERVER to an IIS server.
The configuration:

LocalSqlServer: Server=N-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Rest;Integrated Security=true

RestEntities:   "metadata=res://*/RestEntities.csdl|res://*/RestEntities.ssdl|res://*/RestEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=N-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Rest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

The error that I see in IIS configurations is:
"ExceptionMessage": "The connection string 'RestMarketEntities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute. \" "

- Do I need to set up the PROVIDER NAME in the "providers" directory and the "connection strings" folder on the IIS server?

  - Do I need to change something in the code for it to run on the IIS server?
- Should the CONNECTION STRING in IIS be exactly as it appears in the code?

Thank you

Error:

{

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",

"ExceptionMessage": "The connection string 'RestEntities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute.\"",

"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",

"StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Rest.API.Controllers.CategoriesController.GetAll() in C:\\Users\\n\\VSProjects\\Rest.API\\Rest.API\\Controllers\\CategoriesController.cs:line 17\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

Comment: Show your code and the actual error page or full exception. Connection strings can be configured via IIS Manager or command line, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-3-configure-data-source-settings but you didn't seem to configure that yet.

Comment: Do you have `connectionsStrings` section in your web.config file? Ensure that your connectionstring has `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`. Also, ensure that you website application pool has .NET CLR version set to `.NET Framework 4`